How to create a dock shortcut to an URL to a google doc and make it behave like a webapp?
I tried creating a dock shortcut to a particular doc, using Google Chrome, but every time when Chrome upgrades, the webapp defaults to opening the Google doc (or sheets or slides) landing page, instead of opening the doc/slide/sheet of interest.
Is there a way to manually create that webapp shortcut in OSX (similar to Windows shortcuts with cmd line arguments) so that I can reliably open the actual doc I want in the shortcut.
